# Reflection in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

The following code fails when I invoke the method.  No exceptions; everything just crashes. This code is in a Windows Phone 7 Portable Class Library, any idea what's going on?

```
public static object Deserialize(string input, Type type)
{
    var castMethod = typeof(ModelBase).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(type);
    object castedObject = castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { input });
    return castedObject;
}

public static T Cast<T>(string input)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MakeGenericMethod is present but not supported in Silverlight for Windows Phone.

Check here under "platform notes": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

You don't need reflection here at all. You can replace your `Deserialize(string, Type)` method (and get rid of `Cast<T>`) by simply calling [**`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Type)`**](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm).

**Longer answer:**

Your `Cast<T>` method needlessly complicates things:

- It has a type parameter `T` and returns a `T` object/value, but the calling method (`Deserialize`) doesn't care about this anyway; it returns an "untyped" `object`, so `Cast` could just as well return `object` too.
- Having to transform a `Type` object into the corresponding type argument for `T` means that you need to do some type reflection. However, if `Cast<T>` were not generic — and as pointed out above, it doesn't have to be — you wouldn't need all that reflection.
- As it turns out, Json.NET doesn't require a type parameter `T`, either. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` has a non-generic "overload" that accepts a `Type` object.

Therefore, get rid of your `Cast<T>` method and of your reflection detour and simply use the non-generic [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Type)`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) overload.

**P.S.:** Regarding your original question, according to the ECMA-335 standard, which describes the CLI (which is implemented by .NET, .NET Compact, Silverlight, and WP7), Reflection is not part of the Kernel library, but a separate but optional library. If it is absent on a particular platform (such as on WP7, AFAIK), `Type` objects are essentially to be treated as opaque objects from which you cannot derive other `Type` instances.

Comment: Yeah I figured this out about 10 minutes after I posted this question :P

Thanks for your detailed analysis though.

Comment: Also the Cast is actually required because of what I do with the object once I get it back, it's an "object" but it's still typed.  Too obscure to explain but yes the DeserializeObject overload in Json.NET is exactly what I needed.